# Is OFB-mode a stream-cipher?

Tags: stream-cipher, ofb

I've seen that OFB is considered as a block cipher mode. But could we consider it also as a family of stream cipher?

Comment: OFB is not a block cipher but a block cipher *mode*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Output feedback (OFB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Output_feedback_(OFB)) mode is a [block cipher mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) that turns a block cipher into a synchronous stream cipher.

It is similar to CBC mode with constant encryption of zeros except that the plaintexts x-ored with the output and the output feedback as input to the next encryption. This doesn't mean that encryption is depend on the previous messages or ciphertexts, OFB is **plaintext independent mode**, like any stream cipher; the currently encrypted bytes don't depend on the previously encrypted bytes.

Encryption and decryption are the same;

\begin{align}
C_j &= P_j \oplus O_j\\
P_j &= C_j \oplus O_j\\
O_j &= E_K(I_j)\\
I_j &= O_{j-1}\\
I_0 &= \text{IV}\\
\end{align}

Like CTR mode it produces a key stream and we don't need a PRP here, a PRF can work. However, it doesn't give random access as the CTR mode.

If we consider the [stream cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher) definition of Wikipedia

> In a stream cipher, each plaintext digit is encrypted one at a time with the corresponding digit of the keystream, to give a digit of the ciphertext stream

Yes, it is a family of stream ciphers that can be built from PRP/PRF.

---

It turns out that with high probability [Carl M. Campbell Jr. is the inventor](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/98376/18298) of the OFB mode around 1977. This was the missing point in this answer. Below is the original drawing for OFB mode.

[image]